# Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

I have the following generic method, but VS gives me a compile error on that. (Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T')

```
public static T Method<T>(T model) where T : new()
{
    var m = model ?? new T();
}
```

Does some one have any idea why?

Edit: Is it possible the reason is that T can be a struct in my case, and a struct is an non-nullable type?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should add `class` constraint:

```
public static T Method<T>(T model) where T : class, new()
{
    var m = model ?? new T();

    return m;
}
```

And you should return `m` too!

Note: As @KristofDegrave mentioned in his comment, the reason that we have to add `class` constraint is because T can be a value type, like `int` and since `??` operator (null-coalescing) check on types that can be null, so we have to add `class` constraint to exclude value types.

Edit: Alvin Wong's answer covered the case for nullable types too; which are structs actually, but can be operands of ?? operator. Just be aware that `Method` would return `null` without Alvin's overloaded version, for nullable types.

Comment: why should he `return m` instead of `return model ?? new T();` i thought the result will be the same?

Comment: Of-course they are the same! But in the question the 1st one is used. It's just that I've mentioned.

Comment: Is it possible the reason is that T can be a struct in my case, and a struct is an non-nullable type?

Comment: @KristofDegrave You are right. That's why we have to explicitly add `class` constraint here.

Comment: I would like to give them both, but that isn't possible. Both give an answer to my question, but this is the only answer where my comment got an answer that is why

Comment: @KristofDegrave You could have two overloads, one for classes, one for structs, and then only null coalesce for classes.

Comment: @Servy `Method` here meant to NOT return `null` value. But if we use an overload for structs the we will have another problem with nullable value types. `new T()` (and `default(T)`) returns `null` for nullable value types; for example `new int?()` (and `default(int?)`) is null. How can we deal with them?

Comment: @KavehShahbazian Actually an `int?` cannot be passed to a method with `where T : struct` nor can it be passed to a method that specified `where T : class`.  `Nullable` is such a special case of a type that it was decided it shouldn't meet either condition.  If you do want it to be supported anyway you'd need a third overload for `T?`, but by the sound of it you can just live with it not being something that can be passed in at all because you don't know what the value should be.

Comment: I failed to write an overload for `T?`. Please guide me on that. And good point you've mentioned here; Thanks.

Comment: I would thing the following: public static T? Method<T>(T? model) where T : struct
{
    return model ?? default(T?);
}

Answer (score 86):

`??` is the null-coalescing operator. It can't be applied to non-nullable types. Since `T` can be anything, it can be an `int` or other primitive, non-nullable type.

If you add the condition [`where T : class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) (must be specified before `new()`) it forces `T` to be a class instance, which is nullable.

Comment: Doesn't the new() condition force T to be a nullable type?

Comment: @KristofDegrave no new() only means there will be an empty construtor

Comment: Is it possible the reason is that T can be a struct in my case, and a struct is an non-nullable type?

Answer (score 32):

Many have pointed out already that adding the `class` constraint for the generic will solve the problem.

If you want your method to be applicable to `Nullable<T>` too, you can add an overload for it:

```
// For reference types
public static T Method<T>(T model) where T : class, new()
{
    return model ?? new T();
}

// For Nullable<T>
public static T Method<T>(T? model) where T : struct
{
    return model ?? new T(); // OR
    return model ?? default(T);
}
```

Comment: Tnx for pointing that out, but I don't need to support it for struct values :)

Comment: @KristofDegrave Just pointing out for completeness. Someone else may need it! :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify that your `T` type is a class with a constraint on the generic type:

```
public static T Method<T>(T model) where T : class, new()
{
    return model ?? new T();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since T can be any type, there is no guarantee that T will have a static ?? operator or that the type T is nullable.

[?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for **nullable value types or reference
>   types**.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason the `??` operator can't be used on non-nullable types, even though it is supposed to be equivalent to `model == null ? new T() : model`, and you *are* allowed a null comparison with a non-nullable type.

You can get exactly what you're looking for without any additional constraints by using the ternary operator instead, or an if statement:

```
public static T Method<T>(T model) where T : new()
{
   var m = model == null ? new T() : model;
}
```

Comment: This fails to handle `Nullable<>` types. It returns `null` when `model` is `null`.

Comment: @AlvinWong Well, `var m = new int?()` is supposed to be `null`. For value types, `new T()` is similar to (if not exactly the same as) `default(T)`. If you want to initialize nullable types to something other than the result of the default constructor, then this code is inadequate, but that was not the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

`model ?? new T()` means `model == null ? new T() : model`. It is not guaranteed that model is non-nullable and `==` cannot be applied for `null` and a non-nullable object. Changing constraint to `where T : class, new()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Mark T as "class" and you are good to go.